# How to disable temporary onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have set `window.onbeforeunload` on document ready.

But I need to disable this for a clic in some link:

```
<a href="#downloadTemplate" id="downloadTemplate" title="Descargar Plantilla"><span class="fa fa-file-excel-o fa-2x"></span> </a>
```

I tried:

```
$("#downloadTemplate").mousedown(function () {
    $(window).unbind("beforeunload");
    window.location.href = "/MyLink";
});
```

I tried almost every combination

```
$("#downloadTemplate").click(function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    window.location.href = "/DownloadAFile";
});
```

But nothing works, what am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried `removeEventListener()`?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure but the following should help...

```
$("#downloadTemplate").click(function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```